# How to use ECMAScript 6 syntax with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ecmascript-6

I am interested in using ECMAScript 6 features in my web application which I am developing using Visual Studio 2013. Currently the syntax does not seems to be working, How can I configure VS to make it work?

Comment: I'm not sure If VS 2013 supports ES6, I'd suggest looking into  traceur or another transpiler

Comment: had the same issue. For compilation, i use traceur like @SpencerKillen mentionned, and I disabled syntax error in Tools->Options for javascript editor.

Comment: it may not even come in vs2015 - see http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/7017377-support-for-es6-modules

Comment: THE editor is here! http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2015/06/10/javascript-editor-improvements-in-visual-studio-2015.aspx

Comment: According to this it will be available in VS2015 in the July release. https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/7752489-es6-es2015-support

Comment: An alternative is [Visual Studio Code (freeware)](https://code.visualstudio.com/) which supports ECMAScript 6+

Answer (score 52):

If you have Resharper installed in your VS 2013 - from today on you can [switch to using ES6](http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2015/04/21/typescript-and-ecmascript-6-in-resharper-9-1/):

[image]

Comment: Note that this option only became available in the latest version of ReSharper (9.1). Versions prior to that will *not* show you the "JavaScript language level" option.

Comment: Just tried this out but basic ES6 things like import, export, class, still show up as syntax errors... Guess they're still working on it.

Comment: @JamesReategui you need to turn off the VS syntax checking.  http://i.imgur.com/RCdK7Od.png  Then the syntax errors will go away.

Comment: @GregGum - just tried turning off VS syntax checking and that works better, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

What I've done for the past few years for my VS solutions is to have the latest version of [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) installed.

From there, I whould create an `_buildscripts` directory with a `package.json` file.  (NOTE: make sure to set `private:true` in your package.json)

With that in place I will have a prebuild.cmd (setup as a pre-build script for my project) with something similar to the following...

```
:CHANGE_TO_CURRENT_DIRECTORY
rem Change to this batch file's drive/directory
CD /D "%~dp0"

:INSTALL NODE DEPENDENCIES AND INSTALL - use call, since it's a batch/cmd file
call npm install

:SET YOUR "start" SCRIPT IN package.json TO BE YOUR BUILD
:   such as .... "start":"gulp"
call npm start
```

From here, you can setup [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/), [traceur](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler/wiki/GettingStarted), [browserify](http://browserify.org/) and/or another tools targeting newer javascript concepts.

I'm using git, so detecting new/updated files is far easier than with TFS, but you can script at least the checkout of your output directory for transpiled JavaScript.

You can also use something like [watchify](https://github.com/substack/watchify) or [gulp-watchify](https://github.com/marcello3d/gulp-watchify) for hanling live edits (via a terminal window).

I realize this answer takes you well outside of VS's integrated tooling, there are some integrated tools, like chirpy and others that do these sorts of things, but my experience is they have be sub-par for my needs, and I've been doing more node development lately.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like the best we can do is to vote for [es6 support](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/7017377-support-for-es6-modules).
It's strange for me but [Web Essentials](http://vswebessentials.com/) also doesn't povide ES6 support yet.

As for me I've disabled syntax errors for js files in my VS. Not ideal but at least less eye distracting.