# Visual Studio does not recognize ES6 template strings

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, ecmascript-6

I have issues getting both Visual Studio Code and Visual Studio 2013 to recognize the special syntax of template strings (ES6):

**Visual Studio Code**

[image]

**Visual Studio 2013**

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you using ` (tick) or ' (single quote) ?

Comment: I just looked it up...I wasn't familiar with template strings, and hadn't ever seen the back tick used, looks like it is correct :)

Comment: There was a lot of small things like that that drove me away from visual studio code. You should file it as a bug on git hub  https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues

Comment: The proper name is "template literal" FYI, since if you tag it with something, it doesn't have to return a string :)

Comment: Interesting. I read about them on MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings) and they refer to them as strings. I guess I should also read the official ES6 specification! :-)

Comment: @transporter_room_3 I think you are confusing not *recognizing* the syntax with not coloring it correctly. If you hover over `var test`, you should see it picks it up as a string (`var test: string`). I don't think VS2013 has ES6 support, so it's no surprise you're not getting it there

Comment: You may need to upgrade IDE... First came out in VS2015 https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2015/06/10/javascript-editor-improvements-in-visual-studio-2015/ Duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034668/how-to-use-ecmascript-6-syntax-with-visual-studio-2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be working now, there is no issue for basic examples in VSCode 1.14.0

[image]

I suspect they were just a bit late to the backtick party. There are however still many unclosed issues relating to things like [better support for template grammars](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-TmLanguage/issues/503) and [language support in ES6 template strings](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/5961) so it appears there is much work to do for advanced capabilities being included.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use back ticks (`), not single or double quotes

```
var name = 'Walton';
console.log(`Hi ${name}`);
```