# Syntax error in javascript may be breaking the code

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

I am using below script to read cookie values, it works fine but i want to confirm if this has some syntax error

as when i put this code in VS 2013 it show sytax error red marks around this code

```
[![const input = "{stamp:'HMzWoJn8V4ZkdRN1DduMHLhS3dKiDDr6VoXCjjeuDMO2w6V+n2CcOg==',necessary:true,preferences:true,statistics:true,marketing:false,ver:1}";
const obj = input
  .slice(1, input.length - 1)
  .split(',')
  .reduce((obj, str) => {
    const \[key, val\] = str.split(':');
    obj\[key\] = val;
    return obj;
  }, {});][1]][1]
```

[image]

And when i try to wrap  below statement in try catch it show error

```
try
{
 const input = Cookies.get('CookieConsent');
                    const obj = input
                      .slice(1, input.length - 1)
                      .split(',')
                      .reduce((obj, str) => {
                          const [key, val] = str.split(':');
                        obj[key] = val;
                        return obj;
                       }, {});
}
catch(err)
{
//do something
}
```

[image]

I am not able to figure out if there is any issue with syntax as it works but possible may be breaking the code logic that i have after this [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yENLVZ?editors=1111)

Comment: If it had a syntax error then it wouldn't work?! It's likely VS being rubbish at parsing JS

Comment: the old VS does not know ES6.

Comment: Looks fine to me, It's also ES 2016 arrow functions, VS 2013 probably doesn't understand this as it reasonably new

Comment: Then what is wrong with code when i add it in try catch

Comment: Does the duplicate solve it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034668/how-to-use-ecmascript-6-syntax-with-visual-studio-2013

Comment: I'd recommend [VS code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) for JS, it understands JS a lot better